# Microsoft Face Api response time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, face-detection

I am using microsoft face api from my client side code using java script/Jquery.
Here is the code. I am capturing the image using camera and then convert that image to a blob and send that to the api. I am getting the results. But this api takes around 4-6 seconds to get the results. Is this usual or there could be some performance improvement?

Thank you!

```
var params = {
    // Request parameters
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
    "returnFaceAttributes": "age,gender,glasses",
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        // Request headers
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","Mykey");
    },
    type: "POST",
    // Request body
    data: data,
    processData: false,

})
.done(function(data) {
    console.timeEnd("callMicrosoftService");

    parseData(data);

})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

Comment: Is the measurement of 4-6secs to be understood with or without the time it takes to upload the source picture?

Comment: I am posting the image as a blob in post body. I am not uploading it using a separate request.

Comment: if that means that the time it takes to upload the source picture is included in the 4-6 seconds, that is probably half of it or more... what size (MB?) are the files on average?

Comment: Size of the blob object is .5 MB on average.

Answer (score 0):

The call will return faster if you query less face attributes:

> Note that each face attribute analysis has additional computational and time cost.

Source: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

Its difficult to say whether this is "usual" or not, as it depends on so many factors.

Apart from that, you won't be able to improve much by changing things on client-side, as the actual computation depends on server resource allocation and the quota alloted to your account there.

Comment: Thanks @dlatikay for the response. But I need the attributes because I have to use them further. I understand that actual computation happens on the server. So if i am using paid services instead of free one, the results might be faster you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this API to be a bit slow.  We ended up using [this one](https://www.cloudmersive.com/image-recognition-and-processing-api) instead which is free for 50,000 calls/month.